# RadGrid Doubleclick

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, radgrid

I would like to fire off the server side selectedindexchanged method of a radgrid on doubleclick and not on click. Is it possible to do this???

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridCashier" runat="server" AllowMultiRowSelection="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceCashier" Skin="WebBlue" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowFilteringByColumn="true"
             AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="true" GroupingSettings-CaseSensitive="false" OnDataBound="RadGridCashier_DataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadGridCashier_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="rouse_location,operator_no"   >
                    <Columns>
                       //columns go here
                    </Columns>                        
                </MasterTableView>

                 <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true" EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true">
                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" EnableDragToSelectRows="true" />
                     <ClientEvents OnRowDblClick="RowDblClick" />
                </ClientSettings>

            </telerik:RadGrid>


        function RowDblClick(sender, eventArgs) {
        Row= eventArgs.get_itemIndexHierarchical();
       // here is where i want to fire off selectedindexchanged somehow.

    }
```

Is it possible to do this? To postback on doubleclick or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the enablePostBackOnRowClick attribute is conflicting with your clientEvent.  In your RowDblClick js function, you could perform an ajax call by calling the RadAjaxManager and including a commandArgument to the ajaxRequest() method such as:

```
$find("<%= RadAjaxManager1.ClientID %>").ajaxRequest("SelectedIndexChanged");
```

Then in code behind, handle the RadAjaxManager AjaxRequest event:

```
protected void RadAjaxManager1_AjaxRequest(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Argument == "SelectedIndexChanged")
    {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that too. I don't think there is.

Comment: I updated my post as I realized there is no EnablePostBackOnRowDblClick.  I've implemented the above but I don't know if it will get you what you need.

Comment: Ok you're saying to perform the ajax call in the RowDblClick function??

Comment: Yes...in your js RowDblClick function, call the RadAjaxManager line I included first.